# Naming constants in C++

Tags: c++, constants, naming-conventions, naming

I am replacing my #defines, for instance `#define NUM_SLIDER_POSITIONS 5` for constant variables. Should I keep the old naming like:

```
const unsigned int NUM_SLIDER_POSITIONS = 5;
```

Or should I use something more like:

```
const unsigned int kNumSliderPositions = 5;
```

.

**EDIT**: The post has been put on hold, but anyway I'd like to sum up your answers:

Other option would be using underscores as a separators using lower case letters:

```
const unsigned int num_slider_positions = 5;
```

**Constant identifier.**

Regarding the use of a prefix as a way of identifying constants , the most common options are not using it, as it may not add relevant information:

```
const unsigned int num_slider_positions = 5;
```

Use a "k" before the name:

```
const unsigned int k_num_slider_positions = 5;
```

Or declaring the variable inside a class or namespace, in order to avoid polluting the global scope and providing a more self-explanatory name:

```
namespace defaults // or "config", or "settings" or something like that
{
    const unsigned int num_slider_positions = 5;
}
```

Client code:

```
int slider_positions = defaults::num_slider_positions;
```

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but the answer is neither. `SHOUTY_CAPS` are nasty to read and conventionally reserved for macros, while `pseudoHungarian` notation is utter gibberish. For consistency, I generally follow the standard library's convention of `lower_case`.

Comment: All caps is usually reserved for macros by convention. Just to be clear, in the first example, you don't keep both the define and const right?

Comment: You should use the same convention that you are using *now* in your other own sources. After all, you are the one having to mentally parse them as well. It relieves you from having to remember "oh yeah I replaced this define with a constant" all the time.

Comment: @NeilKirk No, I don't keep them both, thanks. It's edited now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I am replacing my #defines for constant variables.

Kudos! :)

> Should I keep the old naming like: [all-caps]

If the coding conventions of your project designate constants to be in all-caps, you should (as it spares you an effort). **Otherwise, you should not** (because it will be confusing later, for maintenance).

> Or should I use something more like: [bastardized hungarian convention]

This is up to you. Personally I do not like to add weird letters for my constants, because when reading the code - or writing it - I do not care much that they are constant (and if I try to write into them, the compiler will let me know).

My (personal) choice would be to use a namespace for providing context (instead of a prefix), along these lines:

```
namespace defaults // or "config", or "settings" or something like that
{
    const unsigned int num_slider_positions = 5;
}
```

Client code:

```
int slider_positions = defaults::num_slider_positions;
```

I find this to be a superior alternative, because the context is more self-explanatory (than a "k" in front of it, or a "g" or a whatever else).

Comment: Using namespaces might be a good idea, thanks.

Comment: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!" - Tim Peters

Comment: @JosieThompson I was about to write the exact same thing, I've "import this" so many times that now the Zen of Python is almost like a poetry to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you for any name convention. But for C++ code you may also consider putting constants inside a class that use it, instead of pollute the global scope.

Comment: What if more than one class uses the constant?

Comment: @NeilKirk That's a design question. I personally seldom encounter such case since the constants usually "come out" of some object, or otherwise I move it into a configuration/preference, in the rare case or test code for convenience, just keep it in global.

Comment: I put them in namespaces.

Comment: Yeah that works too. That's the idea, which I prefer const over #define.

Answer (score 1):

the naming convention of constant name with C++ is use a **k** followed by mixed case, 
 for constants defined globally or within a class, As a convenience to the reader, compile-time constants of global or class scope follow a different naming convention from other variables. Use a k followed by words with uppercase first letters

```
const unsigned int kNumSliderPositions = 5;
```

[see more](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Constant_Names)

Comment: You make it sound like that is a universally followed naming convention. It isn't.

Comment: @NeilKirk It's so universal that I'd never heard of it before.  (Globally, I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to distinguish constants in the naming convention or not.  I've never worked at a place which did, and of course, one man's constant is another man's variable---on large projects, "constants" tend to be read from a configuration file.)

Comment: FWIW it is Google's convention I believe. I've never seen it anywhere else.

Comment: It is indeed a Google convention. http://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Constant_Names